# about simple scrollable widget

Tags: android-widget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scrollable App widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815572/scrollable-app-widgets)

hello today i read http://code.google.com/p/simplescrollablewidget/ and  http://code.google.com/p/scrollablecontacts/ ,i run this code,very well,but i have a question is that why i run these apps,i need first install ADW Launcher, Launcher Pro. Zeam
or Home++ and so on,why  dev itself  home not upports scrollable widgets,how to modify it can 
upports scrollable widgets.thank you.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815572/scrollable-app-widgets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815572/scrollable-app-widgets) Here i got my answer but this is only possible over api 13
I have not tried in honeycomb...but for ics it works perfect