# Scrollable App widgets

Tags: android, widget, scrollable, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Scrollable App widgets are included in ICS and honeycomb ...for example the mail widget and bookmark widget

I want to code a custom scrollable widget for me for ICS ...
But I am unable to find any source and references..please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Widgets can be used with collections: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections

For example [`android.widget.ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) and [`android.widget.GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html)

Comment: thanks a lot I achieved what i wanted...it was in my mind that i have to use scrollview ...but i used stackview widget example and and just replaced stackview with listview and all done !